# Declaring InputStream

Tags: java, android

I am learning android and new to Java but not new to programming (Using Eclipse). I am trying to execute an example code like this in a method:

```
private void dummy() {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(quakeFeed);
        URLConnection connection;
        connection = url.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection httpconnection = (HttpURLConnection)connection;
        int responseCode = httpconnection.getResponseCode();
        if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            InputStream inp = new BufferedInputStream(httpconnection.getInputStream());
    }
...
}
```

Assume all other syntax and variables defined. I get the following error:

> InputStream` cannot be resolved to a variable.

This is strange even after importing `java.io.InputStream;`

The error goes off if I declare the `InputStream` outside the method, i.e.

```
InputStream inp;
private void dummy() {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(quakeFeed);
        URLConnection connection;
        connection = url.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection httpconnection = (HttpURLConnection)connection;
        int responseCode = httpconnection.getResponseCode();
        if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        // Changed
            inp = new BufferedInputStream(httpconnection.getInputStream());
    }
    ...
}
```

I am curious why a local declaration of `InputStream` could not be resolved but a global declaration is resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `if` statement is followed by a statement. Declaration of a variable would require a block instead. If you were allowed to declare a variable there, it would have no visible scope and serve no purpose.

This should work:

```
if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
{ /* Note the brace to start a block! */
  InputStream inp = new BufferedInputStream(httpconnection.getInputStream());
  /* Now use the stream within the block. */
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
try {
    String fileUrl = "https://www.bps.go.id/publication/download.html?nrbvfeve=MWJlMzhiOWZmMWVkMWRiZDhmMzRlN2Zh&xzmn=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuYnBzLmdvLmlkL3B1YmxpY2F0aW9uLzIwMjMvMTAvMTYvMWJlMzhiOWZmMWVkMWRiZDhmMzRlN2ZhL25lcmFjYS1wZW1lcmludGFoYW4tdW11bS1pbmRvbmVzaWEtMjAxNy0yMDIyLmh0bWw%3D&twoadfnoarfeauf=MjAyMy0xMC0xOSAxMTowNjowMA%3D%3D";
    String outputPath = "C:\\xampp\\New folder";
    URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
    inputStream = url.openStream(); 
    ReadableByteChannel channel = Channels.newChannel(url.openStream());
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(outputPath));
    fos.getChannel().transferFrom(channel, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
    fos.close();
    channel.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```